# Unable to deactivate Object Lock on an Amazon S3 bucket using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to use [`put_object_lock_configuration()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object_lock_configuration) API call to disable object locking on an Amazon S3 bucket using python boto3.

This is how I use it:

```py
response = s3.put_object_lock_configuration(Bucket=bucket_name,
            ObjectLockConfiguration={
                'ObjectLockEnabled': 'Disabled'});
```

I always get exception with the following error.

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the PutObjectLockConfiguration operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema
```

I suspect I miss the 2 parameters 'Token' and 'ContentMD5'. Does anyone know how do I get these values?

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug with boto3. Have you tried the latest version?

Comment: I've figured it out. The only value of 'ObjectLockEnabled' allowed is 'Enabled'. My intention is to disable object lock. but this is not possible. because object lock is defined during bucket creation time and it can't be changed afterward.

However, I can provide empty rule and the retention mode will become 'None', which is essentially no object lock.

Comment: An interesting discovery! Please put your finding in an Answer so that future people can find your solution more easily.

Comment: good to know, thanks for the comments

Answer (score 2):

The only value of 'ObjectLockEnabled' allowed is 'Enabled'. My intention is to disable object lock. but this is not possible. because object lock is defined during bucket creation time and it can't be changed afterward. However, I can provide empty rule and the retention mode will become 'None', which is essentially no object lock.

Comment: Can you please specify how to provide an empty rule? I tried few ways, no luck yet...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the boto3 code for blank retention rule, the precondition is to use mode=GOVERNANCE in the first place.

```
client.put_object_retention(
            Bucket=bucket_name, Key=object_key,
            Retention={},
            BypassGovernanceRetention=True
        )
```